# how to import attachments within comments through csv importer in jira cloud?

Tags: jira

I am able to import the normal attachments in the issue through csv importer.

But how to import the attachments which are in comments?

I am unable to get the attachments in comments into the target jira cloud instance.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In Server at least, the thumbnails in comments come from the regular attachments, just using wiki markup to refer to the attachment